# RCPTT: Invalid eclipse target platform: No name

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rcptt

I want to add a RCPTT test in my RCP eclipse application. When I create a "New application under test", I select the product for which I do my RCPTT test (the location of the plugins folder), but I get the error:

> " Invalid eclipse target platform: No name".

I have tried with RCPTT Tool 2.3.0 and 2.4.2, but none of them works.

Comment: What do you mean by product? Is it an "Eclipse installation" created by Delta-pack or PDE? Could you list the content of this folder?

Comment: I just downloaded rcptt nightly (2.5.0) and worked.

Comment: You mean your problem is solved already?

Comment: yes, is solved if I used RCPTT nightly.